# Or condition not working in nodejs bot

Tags: node.js, bots, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to add an or condition in my below piece of

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    function (session) {
        if (!session.privateConversationData.greetingsDone) {
            session.send("Welcome to Ask Bot.");
            session.privateConversationData.greetingsDone = true;
            //Calling the intermediate dialog
            session.beginDialog('DelveDialog');
        }
        else{
            //If not the first call, go directly to QnADialog
            session.beginDialog('azureQnAMakerDialog') || session.beginDialog('downloadQnAMakerDialog')

        }
    }
```

also tried

```
session.beginDialog('azureQnAMakerDialog'||'downloadQnAMakerDialog')
```

But it is not working. I am not sure is it the problem of session.begindialog function or the problem of or condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the more explicit `if(!session.beginDialog('azureQnAMakerDialog')){ session.beginDialog('downloadQnAMakerDialog');}` ?

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes. I tried but still it is not giving output from second qnamakerdialog

Comment: try giving console in if condition. if working, try commenting session.send()

Comment: @EdwinBabu it is not working that way also.

Comment: refer my code https://gist.github.com/edwinbbu/33bcc0dbcf0e1731bfaa9ec1f8788829